# Is it possible to create a std::map of *CCAnimation objects?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone

They seem to all get autoreleased the moment I create them =s

```
void SceneView::createAnimation(KillerRabbit* killerRabbit, std::string animation) {
    CCArray* animFrames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(15);
    int first = std::stoi(killerRabbit->spriteSheetMap[animation]["FIRST"]);
    int last = std::stoi(killerRabbit->spriteSheetMap[animation]["LAST"]);
    char str[100] = {0};
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        // Obtain frames by alias name
        sprintf(str, (killerRabbit->spriteSheetMap[animation]["KEY"]+"[%d].png").c_str(), i);
        CCSpriteFrame* frame = sharedSpriteFrameCache->spriteFrameByName(str);
        animFrames->addObject(frame);
    }

    spriteAnimationsMap[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation] = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.1f);
    // 14 frames * 1sec = 14 seconds
    rabbitSprites[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation]->
    runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(CCAnimate::create(spriteAnimationsMap[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation])));
}
```

If I omit this part of the code:

```
rabbitSprites[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation]->
runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(CCAnimate::create(spriteAnimationsMap[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation])));
```

And try to access the object in:

```
spriteAnimationsMap[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation]
```

In a later part of the code with another method, the object inside that map would have been autoreleased, how can I retain it so I can use the different animations stored in it at a later time?

Comment: The KillerRabbit is back :)

Comment: This rabbit isn't as deadly as I hope it could be yet =(

Comment: How do you know that it has been released? And why does the `runAction` line of code change that?

Comment: @sftrabbit
I *think* it's a part of the framework I'm using, it has some sort of autorelease mechanism that I can't seem to get to work properly =s I know that the objects are gone due to all the null exceptions the IDE has been throwing at me =(

Comment: It's super heavily nested, my head spins trying to trace the code back into it's roots, what should I do in a situation like this? Each method contains 5 more within, and those contains 5 more too =s

Comment: @Hobbyist It doesn't sound like some kind of garbage collection if it's somehow magically setting the value in your map to a null pointer. I could understand if you got segmentation faults, but to have null pointers in there, you have to be putting them in there. Have you tried checking that the value of `spriteAnimationsMap[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation]` is not null immediately?

Comment: @sftrabbit
I did that by moving the method which accesses that map into a single quarantined method, and it immediately throws a null exception.

Comment: @Hobbyist Check if `CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.1f)` is just giving you a null pointer. Literally right after that line, see if it is null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27590/discussion-between-hobbyist-and-sftrabbit)

Comment: doesn't cocos2d-x have a retain mechanism if it supports autoreleasing in c++?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, silly me, I had to do this:

```
spriteAnimationsMap[killerRabbit->spriteName][animation]->retain();
```